# Residual analysis and subtracting values between scatter plots

Tags: tableau-api

[image]
I am trying to subtract the two corresponding values for each of the scatter plots  to get a residual. Each point on the scatter plot below has a corresponding point in the plot above, but simply with a different value. For example, NE at the very left has a value of 0.5 in the top scatter plot and I'd like to subtract from it the value in the bottom plot which is 1. I have been trouble doing this. I couldn't get a level of detail calculation to work, because that aggregates everything, and I simply can't make a table calculation of avg(average scores) - predicted score. The predicted score is really just a trend line fitted on to the top scatter plot. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post sample data

Comment: Also post the definition of the calculated fields. Otherwise, anyone who tries to help you has to guess what you’re doing